# how can I run my android app?

Tags: android

Unable to run my android app because it runs the image I stored in res/drawable file whenever I click the "run app" application.

I imported an image in the drawable folder of my android project, and then set it as background for main activity, but when I try to run the app instead it displays the image file.

also the following message is displayed in the gradle build.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\GoGetIt\app\src\main\res\drawable\GGIMain.jpg: Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])

This is my activity_main.xml coding

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
\\\android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/GGIMain">
```

Comment: What do you mean it `runs the image`? And it's normal for your code to be analyzed before it's run. If the image doesn't exist or isn't named correctly, you won't be able to run the app.

Comment: what? What's your question?

Comment: Are you saying it shows the image GGIMain that you stored in your drawable folder whenever you run the app? If so, it should, that is what that layout does.

Comment: Just edited the question please see.

Comment: @aniketagarwal did any of the answers below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your naming of the background:

```
android:background="@drawable/GGIMain">
```

This filename (and corresponding xml entry) should be renamed to

```
android:background="@drawable/ggimain">
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename your background image so it has only lower case letters. Then adjust your xml accordingly.

See here for naming rules of resources: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove the background.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    

android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
">
```

Comment: But sir I wish to add the background.